# How do I detect a transition end without a JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, callback, css-transitions, custom-event

I'd like to delete an object after it's done animating with a CSS transition, but I'm not able to use a JavaScript library.

How do I detect when the animation is done? Do I use a **callback** or **custom event** somehow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
element.addEventListener('transitionend', function(event) {
    alert("CSS Property completed: " + event.propertyName);
}, false );
```

For now, the exact event name has not been standardized. Here's a quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition):

> There is a single event that is fired when transitions complete.
>   In all standard-compliant browser, the event is `transitionend`,
>   in WebKit it is `webkitTransitionEnd`.

Here's the fiddle for Webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/bNgWY/

Comment: How do I assign this to a particular transition, like opacity?

Comment: @Wraith - You cannot assign it to a particular transition. Rather, you listen to the event firing on the element. You can then get the information you are looking for from the event object. See my update.

Comment: @Wraith: Look for "Detecting the completion of a transition" on the page Joseph linked to. `propertyName`: A string indicating the name of the CSS property whose transition completed.
`elapsedTime`: A float indicating the number of seconds the transition had been running at the time the event fired. This value isn't affected by the value of transition-delay .

Answer (score 4):

As I'm currently doing the exact same thing I'll share a useful, cross-browser implementation from a [Marakana](http://marakana.com/static/bookshelf/css3_transitions_tutorial/javascript.html) tutorial.

```
   // First, we store the names of the event according to the browsers
            
   var navigatorsProperties=['transitionend','OTransitionEnd','webkitTransitionEnd'];

            //For each of them...
            for (var i in navigatorsProperties) {
                //We attach it to our overlay div
                el.addEventListener(navigatorsProperties[i],function()
                {
                    // Here's the code we want to fire at transition End
                      console.log('transition end');

                },false);
            }
```

It's to be noted that **IE10** supports transitions with `transitionend` (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#mstransitionend)).

**IE9** and below do **not** support transitions (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) ) so you won't be able to attach any eventListener to a transition end ( so don't try `msTransitionend` or whatever for those browsers).

**EDIT:** While reading Modernizr documentation on Github I stumbled on their cross-browser polyfills page. Among many other useful links I found this small but extremely good [transitionend script](https://github.com/EvandroLG/transitionEnd/).

Mind that the examples in the Github README.md use jQuery but the library indeed requires **no libraries** and **no dependencies** as it's written in vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a suitable 'transitionend' polyfill that met my requirements. So if you want something for hooking the transition end once, use this:

```
(function() {
    var i,
        el = document.createElement('div'),
        transitions = {
            'transition':'transitionend',
            'OTransition':'otransitionend',  // oTransitionEnd in very old Opera
            'MozTransition':'transitionend',
            'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
        };

    var transitionEnd = '';
    for (i in transitions) {
        if (transitions.hasOwnProperty(i) && el.style[i] !== undefined) {
            transitionEnd = transitions[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    Object.prototype.onTransitionEndOnce = function(callback) {
        if (transitionEnd === '') {
            callback();
            return this;
        }
        var transitionEndWrap = function(e) {
            callback(); 
            e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, transitionEndWrap);
        };
        this.addEventListener(transitionEnd, transitionEndWrap);
        return this;
    };
}());
```