# Prevent new CSS3 & jQuery animation until previous one has completed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

**What I'm doing:**

I'm utilizing a jQuery plugin called [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to take care of some 3D animations in a responsive slideshow.

**Question:**

Everything works great until you hit "next" or "previous" quickly- before the animation has completed. I've seen a few similar questions, but the answers don't seem to work for me since these technically CSS animations. **How can I disable the ability to navigate until the animation is complete?**

*I should also note that am using keypress now, but I will also have buttons to click in the final version. So the method should work even if there are a few different ways to engage the slideshow.*

**Working Example ›** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/tgR9x/)

**Stripped Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Define the function to play forward
function playForward() {
    // Do Stuff
}

// Define the function to play reverse
function playReverse() {
    // Do Stuff
}

// Animate on keypress
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
        arrow = {
            left: 37,
            up: 38,
            right: 39,
            down: 40
        }, $status = $('#status');

    switch (keyCode) {
        case arrow.left:
            playReverse();
            break;
        case arrow.up:
            //
            break;
        case arrow.right:
            playForward();
            break;
        case arrow.down:
            //
            break;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to keep track of the animation process.
When you trigger the animation on keypress set the variable to true;

```
var isTransitioning = true;
```

At the top of your play functions add this line to detect if it's in transition if it is don't execute the function.

```
if ( isTransitioning ) { return false; }
```

Detect the end of the transition [How do I detect a transition end without a JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814631/how-do-i-detect-a-transition-end-without-a-javascript-library) and set the variable back to false.

Comment: I've tried implementing this method but haven't gotten it to work. Here's the jsFiddle with comments showing what I updated: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/tgR9x/2/ I'm guessing I'm doing the transition end thing wrong.